# Why does distention of the veins not decrease their resistance in the first case but decrease it in the second?

Tags: physiology, blood-circulation

Here are two quotes from *Guyton and Hall Textbook of Medical Physiology*, Chapter 20 (emphasis mine):

> 1. Why is venous resistance so important in determining the resistance to venous return? The answer is that when the **resistance in the veins increases**, blood begins to be dammed up, mainly in the veins themselves. However, the venous pressure rises very little because the veins are highly **distensible**. Therefore, this rise in venous pressure is not very effective in **overcoming the resistance**, and blood flow into the right atrium decreases drastically.

> 2. A sudden increase in blood volume of about 20% increases the cardiac output to about 2.5 to 3 times normal. An analysis of this effect is shown in [Figure 20-15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eOMf.png). Immediately on infusing the large quantity of extra blood, the increased filling of the system causes the Psf to increase to 16 mm Hg, which shifts the venous return curve to the right. At the same time, the increased blood volume **distends the blood vessels, reducing their resistance and thereby reducing the resistance to venous return**, which rotates the curve upward. As a result of these two effects, the venous return curve of Figure 20-15 is shifted to the right. This new curve equates with the cardiac output curve at point B, showing that the cardiac output and venous return increase 2.5 to 3 times and that the right atrial pressure rises to about +8 mm Hg.

The quotes are from different sections of the chapter, so I believe they are unrelated. It seems that the distensibility of the veins doesn't cause their resistance to decrease in the first case, but does in the second case. Why?

Comment: Resistance clearly changes in the first case, as the paragraph is describing what happens *specifically when resistance increases*, which in turn leads to changes in venous volume. The second case is completely different, it is describing what happens *when volume increases*. Please think about it a bit and clarify your question.

Comment: @BryanKrause I've changed the title to make it better correspond to the question in the body of the post.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense, though. In the first case the scenario is that the resistance is increased. You seem to be asking "Why doesn't resistance decrease when resistance increases?"

Comment: @BryanKrause I'm asking why it doesn't decrease despite the high distensibility of the veins. Look at the second quote: *the increased blood volume distends the blood vessels, reducing their resistance*. I assume the blood also distends the veins in the first case, but why doesn't that cause the resistance to decrease, as in the second case?

Comment: Because the scenario there is that the resistance is increased... that's your given. Think if you were solving an electricity problem using I = V/R - if I said "R is increased" you'd know that either I must decrease or V must increase for the equation to hold. If you were then told that also "I is unchanged" you would then know that V must have increased; you would not ask "why isn't R decreased" when that happens.